# Uploading to Youtube via a proxy using the Java Youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

So I want to write a servlet which uploads a video to a youtube channel using the Java API, but I can't seem to find a way of specifying that I want to go through a proxy server. I've seen an example on this site where someone managed to do this using C#, but the Classes they used don't seem to exist in the Java API. Has anybody managed to successfully do this?

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID, developerKey);

Comment: If you provide a link to that other question using C#, someone might tell you how to do the same thing in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new here so I'm unable to comment on posts (and a little late on this topic), but Jesper, I believe this is the C# sample that the original poster was talking about: [How to upload to YouTube using the API via a Proxy Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374187/how-to-upload-to-youtube-using-the-api-via-a-proxy-server)

I can see no "direct" way of porting that example to Java though, since the GDataRequestFactory doesn't seem to have any proxy-related fields.

I was also having issues with the Java client Library with proxy in our application. Basically, the library picks up the global Java proxy settings:

```
System.getProperty("http.proxyHost");
System.getProperty("http.proxyPort");
```

but for some reason not everywhere. To be more precise, even with a proxy server properly configured in Java, YouTube authentication (calling service.setUserCredentials("login", "pwd")) would use a direct connection and ignore the proxy. But a video upload (calling service.insert(...)) would use the proxy correctly.

With the help of folks at the official YouTube API mailing list, I was able to nail this down. The issue is that the authentication is performed using SSL (HTTPS) and since there is a different set of properties for the HTTPS proxy, this didn't work. The fix is to simply set **https.proxy*** properties as well (in addition to **http.proxy***), so that these point to a valid proxy server too:

```
System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
System.getProperty("https.proxyPort");
```