# Call Youtube API requests over a proxy

Tags: php, proxy, youtube-api

I would like to make Youtube requests over a proxy but it seems the Google client library doesn't support this. Also, there is a solution for that in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887717/uploading-to-youtube-via-a-proxy-using-the-java-youtube-api) but unfortunately it depends on the system proxy settings. Is there any other to do that with PHP?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.