# Set proxy for Google.Apis.YouTube.v3

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have the following bit of code to make a call to the

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApiKey = AppSettings.Variables.YouTube_APIKey,
    ApplicationName = AppSettings.Variables.YouTube_AppName
});

Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.VideosResource.ListRequest request = service.Videos.List("snippet,statistics");
request.Id = string.Join(",", videoIDs);
VideoListResponse response = request.Execute();
```

This all works but when we deploy it to our live server, it needs to get through a proxy so we put the following into the web.config:

```
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://192.111.111.102:8081" />
    </defaultProxy>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working as when the call is made, I get the following error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 216.58.213.74:443

Is there a way to manually set the proxy in code?

Something along the lines of:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("192.111.111.102", 8081);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppSettings.Variables.ProxyUser, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyPassword, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyDomain);

// apply this to the service or request object here
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374187/how-to-upload-to-youtube-using-the-api-via-a-proxy-server) if it can help you.

Comment: @KENdi, I saw that answer, unfortunately a video list request doesn't allow you to attach a proxy like the YouTubeRequest in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around this I had to make a webrequest to the url and map the result back to the `VideoListResponse` object:

```c#
try
{
    Uri api = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={0}&key={1}&part=snippet,statistics", videoIds, AppSettings.Variables.YouTube_APIKey));
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(api);

    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(AppSettings.Variables.ProxyAddress, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyPort);
    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppSettings.Variables.ProxyUsername, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyPassword, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyDomain);
    request.Proxy = proxy;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoListResponse>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorLog.LogError(ex, "Video entity processing error: ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course!

You can set a `System.Net.WebProxy` for a `YouTubeService` instance:

```
var _youtubeService = new YouTubeService(yourInitializer);

_youtubeService.HttpClient.MessageHandler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(your parameters..)
};
```

**NOTE** : Don't forget to set other `HttpClientHandler` properties if needed(for example `AutomaticDecompression`)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @ABS looks more efficient and "compact" to me.

Here's how i use it in VB.NET with the Youtube Channel API:

```
Dim uriProxy As New Uri("*proxy_url:IP*")
Dim wpyProxy As New WebProxy With {.Address = uriProxy }

Dim get_youtube_channel_channel_work As New youtube_channel
Dim youtube_initialiser As New Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
youtube_initialiser.ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("youtube_api_key")
youtube_initialiser.ApplicationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("youtube_api_application_name")

Dim youtube_service As Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService = New YouTubeService(youtube_initialiser)
Dim objChannelListRequest As ChannelsResource.ListRequest = youtube_service.Channels.List("id, snippet, statistics")
youtube_service.HttpClient.MessageHandler.InnerHandler = New HttpClientHandler With {.Proxy = wpyProxy}
```