# YouTube .NET API v3 Custom HttpClient

Tags: c#, proxy, youtube-api

I was working on a .NET-based Youtube API client with some simple features. I went on creating a service instance like this:

```
youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApiKey = "",
    ApplicationName = "my_wonderful_client"
});
```

However, I also need it to be able to use proxy to make a connection, so I went on like:

```
if (useProxy)
        {
            Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableHttpClient customClient = null;

            string proxyUri = "http://proxy.proxy.com";
            NetworkCredential proxyCreds = new NetworkCredential(
                @"domain\user",
                "pass123"
            );
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, 8080)
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = proxyCreds,
            };


            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = proxy,
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            };

            Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler customHandler = new Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler(httpClientHandler);
            customClient = new Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableHttpClient(customHandler);
        }
```

Now how do I use my customClient to initialize the connection? Alas, the docs on .NET API are quite scarce.

Thank you.

Comment: Abielita, thank you for answering. Unfortunately, the first method is related to an older version of the API, while the second solution is not really very much different from using raw HTTP/JSON communication with the API without having to use any library. I believe, there must be some simple solution in a framework as elaborate as this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374187/how-to-upload-to-youtube-using-the-api-via-a-proxy-server) on how to use the API via a Proxy Server. Here is the sample code:

```
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
GDataRequestFactory f = (GDataRequestFactory) request.Service.RequestFactory;
IWebProxy iProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(iProxy.GetProxy(query.Uri));
// potentially, setup credentials on the proxy here
myProxy.Credentials = CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials;
myProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
f.Proxy = myProxy;
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390712/set-proxy-for-google-apis-youtube-v3) also suggested to make a webrequest to the url and map the result back to the `VideoListResponse` object:

```
try
{
    Uri api = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={0}&key={1}&part=snippet,statistics", videoIds, AppSettings.Variables.YouTube_APIKey));
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(api);

    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(AppSettings.Variables.ProxyAddress, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyPort);
    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppSettings.Variables.ProxyUsername, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyPassword, AppSettings.Variables.ProxyDomain);
    request.Proxy = proxy;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoListResponse>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorLog.LogError(ex, "Video entity processing error: ");
}
```

You can also check this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup#net) on how to use an HTTP proxy with the .NET client library.